# Selecting Top 100 Largest Values In A Table Given Possible Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, steam

I have a table with the following structure - steamid, itemid, eventid, value , all just ints or big ints that log hourly data I insert. So a user most likely has multiple entries with the same steamids, itemids, and even values.

I'm trying to get the 100 top values - but the same item must not repeat.

What I have so far is

```
SELECT itemid,value,steamid 
FROM $table 
GROUP BY itemid 
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

Which gives me this data set (sample only here):

```
itemid      value   steamid
=================================================
599291414   66397   76561198032389066
779150329   62882   76561198001229760
773965297   51895   76561198014617403
332883551   43201   76561197992659494
333434836   40880   7656119799359013
```

However, this for some reason ignores the true largest value listed in the table. I'm not sure how else I can format this so that I can ignore duplicate entries with the same itemid and steamid. I don't think I can group by steamid because then it would ignore other items that could be associated with a steamid.

Here's the first few if I select without grouping.

```
 itemid     value   steamid
 =====================================
 1011809265 753665  76561198010314894
 376615188  101684  76561197989760193
 478937438  83448   76561198010314894
 478937438  83448   76561198010314894
 376662587  72693   76561197989760193
 376662587  72693   76561197989760193
 599291414  66454   76561198032389066
 599291414  66454   76561198032389066
 599291414  66454   76561198032389066
```

Insight appreciated and I'll gladly answer any questions that may help in figuring this out.

Comment: I don't think you need the join, could you not just wrap `value` with the MAX() functionality. I.E. `SELECT itemid,max(value),steamid FROM supportContacts GROUP BY itemid ORDER BY value DESC`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d711/25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM (

  SELECT itemid,value,steamid FROM $table GROUP BY itemid ORDER BY value DESC
) as tbl1

GROUP BY itemid, value

LIMIT 0,100
```

This should unique itemid, but then give you only the single values.

Comment: I don't think you need the join, could you not just wrap `value` with the MAX() functionality. I.E. `SELECT itemid,max(value),steamid FROM supportContacts GROUP BY itemid ORDER BY value DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding Distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemid, value, steamid 
FROM $table 
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: Group By on MySql is being used for distinct

Comment: Won't that return all the rows, because your checking for a distinct itemid, value, steamid combination?

Comment: @Jeemusu what do you expect to retrieve from the query? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm not the original OP, but I got the impression thats what he/she was asking.

Comment: You will get multiple entries of the itemid if you use distinct in this way, as I mentioned earlier. Here is a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b9ab/1

Comment: This is actually causing multiple entries of the same itemid to be repeated. How can I prevent multiple entries with the same itemid from appearing in the result set?